# Android application crashes on trying to inflate map layout on some devices but works fine on latest devices

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

This is my layout file:

My xml file which contains the map layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
    </fragment>
</FrameLayout>
```

My FragmentClass

```
public class RouteFragment extends Fragment {

    GoogleMap map;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout,container,false);
        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(MainActivity.lng1);

        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        map.addMarker(options);
        options.position(MainActivity.lng2);
        map.addMarker(options);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(MainActivity.lng1));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8));
        if(getArguments().getInt("Driving")==1)
             map.addPolyline(MainActivity.lineOptions);
        else {
            Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(MainActivity.lng1, MainActivity.lng2)
                    .width(5)
                    .color(Color.RED));
        }
        return v;
      }
    }
```

Here is the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
```

Manifest file:

I have requested the desired permissions and defined the uses-library for incroporating maps in the application.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
 <permission
        android:name="com.city.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.city.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Try changing `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` for `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Comment: I did. Didnt work. Its crashing in jelly bean working in kitkat and above

Comment: Could you show your `onCreate`?

Comment: SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();


        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(MainActivity.lng1);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        map.addMarker(options);

Comment: You should edit your question to add the code instead of addding it in the comments. Can you also share all your `onCreate` method?

Comment: how to edit question